# Get Last two folder's name from URL using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have a URL  and from which i need to get names after "**bussiness**" and Before the Page Name i.e. "**paradise-villas-little.aspx**" from below URL.

**http://test.com/anc/bussiness/accommo/resort/paradise-villas-little.aspx**

I am not getting how can i get this. i have tried the RawUrl, but it fetched the full. Please help me how can i do this.

UPDATE: This is a type of URL, i need to check it for dynamically.

Comment: String.IndexOf or regex?

Comment: @VMAtm URL is dynamic, I need to get everything between "Bussiness" and "PageName"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a little helper, and parse the URL from it's `Uri` `Segments` :

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<String> ExtractSegments(this Uri uri, String exclusiveStart)
    {
        bool startFound = false;
        foreach (var seg in uri.Segments.Select(i => i.Replace(@"/","")))
        {
            if (startFound == false)
            {
                if (seg == exclusiveStart)
                    startFound = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!seg.Contains("."))
                    yield return seg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this :

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://test.com/anc/bussiness/accommo/resort/paradise-villas-little.aspx");
var found = uri.ExtractSegments("bussiness").ToList();
```

Then `found` contains "accommo" and "resort", and this method is extensible to any URL length, with or without file name at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing sophisticated in this implementation, just regular string operations:

```
        string url = "http://test.com/anc/bussiness/accommo/resort/paradise-villas-little.aspx";
        string startAfter = "business";
        string pageName = "paradise-villas-little.aspx";
        char delimiter = '/'; //not platform specific

        var from = url.IndexOf(startAfter) + startAfter.Length + 1;
        var to = url.Length - from - pageName.Length - 1;

        var strings = url.Substring(from, to).Split(delimiter);
```

You may want to add validations though.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use built-in string methods. The best is to use String Split.

```
String url = "http://test.com/anc/bussiness/accommo/resort/paradise-villas-little.aspx";
String[] url_parts = url.Split('/'); //Now you have all the parts of the URL all folders and page. Access the folder names from string array.
```

Hope this helps